# Matrix similar to its inverse

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inverse

I have this problem:

$A$ is an $n \times n$-matrix, its characteristic polynomial is $P(X)=(X-1)^n$. Prove that $A$ is similar to its inverse.

How do you solve it? I really don't know.

Comment: Do you know Jordan canonical form?

Comment: yes, i know it quite well.

Comment: So what are the possible Jordan canonical forms of $A$? What do you deduce about $A^{-1}$?

Comment: I know that the Jordan canonical form is made up by some blocks with eigenvalue 1. I think the inverse is an upper triangular matrix with (1 -1 1 -1 ...) sequences in the rows.

Comment: Yes, but those are similar, by either explicit or theoretical considerations.

Comment: the inverse matrix has an upper triangular block on the diagonal for every jordan block (same sizes) in the matrix A. But how can I say they are definitely similar?

Comment: Theoretically, the eigenvalues and block sizes uniquely determine Jordan form. Concretely, make a change of basis by negating some of the basis vectors.

Comment: I think I get it, but maybe i've to study more about the Jordan form.

Comment: Write it up when you've got it. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hints.** Call the underlying field $\mathbb{F}$. We will use the following fact:

> If the characteristic polynomial of a matrix $B\in M_n(\mathbb{F})$ can be factored into linear factors over $\mathbb{F}$ (i.e. if $B$ has a complete set of eigenvalues in $\mathbb{F}$), $B$ is similar to its Jordan form over $\mathbb{F}$.

1. Show that $A$ is is similar to its Jordan form over $\mathbb{F}$. So, it suffices to prove the problem statement for a single Jordan block.
2. From now on, suppose $A$ is an $n\times n$ Jordan block whose characteristic polynomial is $(x-1)^n$. Show that $A$ is invertible.
3. For any positive integer $m$, prove that $(A-I)^m=0$ if and only if $(A^{-1}-I)^m=0$.
4. Hence show that the minimal polynomial of $A^{-1}$ is $(x-1)^n$ and that $A^{-1}$ is similar to $A$ over $\mathbb{F}$.

Comment: how do i show $4.$? i could not find a straight forward way. @user1551

Comment: @Noobmathematician I have replaced the old answer with a (hopefully) simpler one. Please see my new edit. As for step 4 of my old answer, as $A^{-1}-I=J+J^2+\cdots+J^{n-1}$, one can prove by mathematical induction that $(A^{-1}-I)^m$ is a polynomial in $J$ and whose lowest degree term is $J^m$. Therefore $(A^{-1}-I)^m$ is nonzero for $m=1,2,\ldots,n-1$ and $(A^{-1}-I)^n=0$. Hence the minimal polynomial of $A^{-1}$ is $(x-1)^n$ and the Jordan form of $A^{-1}$ is $A$.

Comment: that will be $A^{-1}-I=-J+J^2+\cdots+(-1)^{n-1}J^{n-1}$ right?

Comment: @Noobmathematician Ahh, right. I forgot the sign. But the gist of the argument remains the same.