# Let $A$ is nonsingular and each eigenvalue of $A$ is either $+1$ or $-1$.Why $A$ is similar to ${A^{ - 1}}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $A \in {M_n}$ is nonsingular and each eigenvalue of $A$ is either $+1$ or $-1$.Why $A$ is similar to ${A^{ - 1}}$?

Answer (score 3):

Characteristic equation of the matrix $A$ is of the form $(x-1)^a(x+1)^b$.
Since it is product of linear factors, it is similar to a matrix in Jordan form. You can continue from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/431668/matrix-similar-to-its-inverse)

Answer (score -1):

The eigenvalues of $A^{-1}$ are the reciprocals of the eigenvalues of $A$. By definition, similair matrices have the same eigenvalues.

The proof that $A^{-1}$ and $A$ have the same eigenvalues is simple:
$$Ax=\lambda x \iff A^{-1}Ax = A^{-1} \lambda x \iff \frac{1}{\lambda} x = A^{-1}x$$

Comment: We don't know that $A$ is diagonalisable. It might not even _have_ eigenvalues.

Comment: @Arthur By hypothesis the eigenvalues of $A$ are $\pm 1$. This does not imply it's diagonalisable though :-)

Comment: @Arthur: It will still have eigenvalues in the general sense of generalized eigenvectors and generalized eigenspaces for the Jordan Normal Form.

Comment: "By definition, similar matrices have the same eigenvalues." Nope. Similar matrices have the same eigenvalues, but matrices with the same eigenvalues need not to be similar.

Comment: Similar implies same eigen values but the converse need not be true.