# I have a complex square matrix with the only eigenvalues being $1$ and $-1$. Show that $A$ and the inverse of this matrix $A^{-1}$ are similar

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I was thinking I use the formula for Jordan blocks I have $J=P^{-1} AP$ where

$$J= \left[\begin{array}{rr} 1 & 0 
 \\0  &-1 \end{array}\right]$$

Then $J^{-1}=P A^{-1}P^{-1}$

I can note $J=J^{-1}$

Then could I set the two sides equal? As in

$P^{-1} AP=P A^{-1}P^{-1}$ when simplifying $A=A^{-1}$

Thus proving similarity? I'm not entirely sure if my logic here is sound however.

Comment: Why would the matrix be diagonalizable?

Comment: Assuming $A$ is $2\times 2$, then I think that's basically the idea. You could also note that since $A$ has two distinct eigenvalues it is diagonalizable. This would be pretty much the same proof, but you wouldn't have to leverage the Jordan Form (which is strong result).

Comment: Duplicate questions: [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1269763/let-a-is-nonsingular-and-each-eigenvalue-of-a-is-either-1-or-1-why-a?noredirect=1&lq=1), [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1284461/if-each-eigenvalueof-a-is-either-1-or-1-rightarrow-a-is-similar-to?rq=1) and [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1289878/each-eigenvalue-of-a-is-equal-to-pm-1-why-is-a-similar-to-a-1?rq=1).

Answer (score 2):

If you regard your basis of eigenvectors $(v_i)_{i=1}^n$ then you know
\begin{align*}
Av_i = \pm v_i\quad \text{and} \quad AAv_i = v_i
\end{align*}
Now you know every $x\in \mathbb{C}^n$ can be written as $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i$ for certain $x_i \in \mathbb{C}$. By using the linearity of the matrix multiplication you receive
\begin{align*}
 AAx = AA\sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i AAv_i = \sum_{i=1}^n x_i v_i = x
\end{align*}
So $A$ is its own inverse.

Comment: Can you apply your result to $A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\0 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: How do you know that $A$ is diagonalizable?

Comment: @amd you are right, I don't. I assumed that it is and every eigenvalue is $\pm 1$. I will think about what follows when there are generalized eigenvectors.